# How do I get actions from a telephone-type keyboard's accessory buttons?

Tags: uikeyboard, uikeyboardtype

**Scenario:** I'm working with an existing project that uses a *telephone-based keyboard* which has one or more stored phone numbers in its accessory view.

I'm told that this particular accessory view is **non-custom, build in, de facto**.

I understand that I can trap for each character input via a delegate.

**Question:** How do I capture the ACTIONS of the phone buttons so I can glean the numbers?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The source of the problem was the custom filtering of the host UITextField; not the keyboard itself.  The event handler is actually the UITextField delegate.